# Google python map-reduce library returning a NULL context

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, mapreduce

In my mapper, the context is being returned as NULL

```
class DeleteOldObservationsMapper(object):
  """Mapper for deleting old observations."""

  def __init__(self):
      logging.info('DeleteOldObservationsMapper init')
      ctx = mapreduce.context.get()
      when = ctx.mapreduce_spec.mapper.params.get('before_timestamp_seconds')
      assert when
      self.before_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(when)
      logging.info('before_datetime %s', self.before_datetime)
```

Here is the error trace:

```
ERROR    2013-05-24 16:03:38,662 webapp2.py:1552] 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
'mapreduce_spec'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 66, in post
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 320, in handle
    tstate = model.TransientShardState.from_request(self.request)
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/mapreduce/model.py", line 993, in from_request
    handler = mapreduce_spec.mapper.handler
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/mapreduce/model.py", line 618, in get_handler
    return util.handler_for_name(self.handler_spec)
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/mapreduce/util.py", line 149, in handler_for_name
    return getattr(resolved_name.im_class(), resolved_name.__name__)
  File "/Users/leoromanovsky/code/adapt/server/jobs.py", line 22, in __init__
    when = ctx.mapreduce_spec.mapper.params.get('before_timestamp_seconds')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapreduce_spec'
```

Comment: Annie, leo, is the issue you're seeing this: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=127

Comment: Bert -- I am seeing that same callstack, but I have "threadsafe: false" in my app.yaml, so I don't believe I am running in threadsafe mode.

Comment: You can try to add a pdb before the line that causes the issue and try to see if your object is what is expected

Comment: Paco - by "your object" do you mean ctx? mapreduce.context.get() is definitely returning None. mapreduce.context is the correct module.

Answer (score 2):

We recently hit this problem with a `threadsafe: false` project, and were able to resolve the issue by changing how were were importing the `context` module.  Kevin explains the issue well in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=127).

> kevin.mo...@gmail.com Maybe this will help someone else, but I was seeing this issue and just figured it out for my use case. In our
>   project, we have the mapreduce library in subfolders
>   "libs/external/mapreduce" and not the root of our project.
>
> The library imports context (among other things) from itself as `from
>   mapreduce import context`. So to make it work we are using import
>   manipulation like so:
>
> ```
> import os, sys 
> sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs/external'))
> ```
>
> However, in a few places in our code we were still importing context
>   like so:
>
> ```
> from libs.external.mapreduce import context
> ```
>
> This will actually cause context to get imported twice and
>   `mapreduce.context.Context._local` will get set twice, thus having two
>   different instances of `thread._local`. When `Context._set` is called to
>   store the context for later retrieval in a mapper function or
>   something, it will be using the original `thread._local` instance.
>
> Later when our mapper module imports context again, it gets a new
>   `thread._local` instance. When we were then `calling context.get()` it was
>   returning the new instance which didn't actually have the context:
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapreduce_spec'
> ```
>
> Switching all our imports to `from mapreduce import context`
>   fixed it for us.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer to your problem:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=127

mapreduce.context.get() is simply not threadsave...

So what you could do is to pack it into a wrapper which makes it threadsave then by using a Lock mechanism.

Comment: Like the commenter on that bug, I'm seeing the problem with threadsafe: false